# jmeter - I would like to know if it's possible to have login as part of the set up and logout as part of tear down for 250 concurrent users

Tags: jmeter

I have scenario where I want to run load test for 250 users.
Ramp up time is 10 mins for 250 users and run test for 50 min duration.

Question 1 : Is it recommended to do login and login out as part of set and tear down .. as the dev team does not measure login and log out .?

Question 2 : How do i keep the the  other thread group in loops during the 50 min duration . ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I wouldn't go for it as normally different thread groups should represent the different groups of virtual users, setUp thread group is for accomplishing the pre-conditions for the test and tearDown thread group is for cleaning everything up. If you perform the login in the setup thread group - there will be negative consequences like having to pass login context (tokens, headers, cache, etc.) to other thread groups. So I would rather move login to be the integral part of the main thread group and if needed remove login/logout via [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) (not part of vanilla JMeter, can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))
2. It can be done on either on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level like this:

   [image]

   or you can "loop" the arbitrary part of the test by putting it under the [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller):

   [image]